# PyTorch: Calculating Top Eigenvector of Symmetric Matrix

Tags: python, pytorch, eigenvector

I am looking to find only the primary eigenvector of a real, positive-definite symmetric 20x2000x2000 PyTorch tensor:

```
K = torch.random.randn(20, 2000, 2000)
K_sym = K+K.transpose(1,2)/2
eig, ev = torch.symeig(K_sym, eigenvectors=True)
ev = ev[:,1999,:]

ev.shape

> torch.Size[20, 2000]
```

This implementation is very slow, even on the GPU,

Can anyone suggest a faster way of finding the first eigenvector?

For example, power iteration may be a solution. I have based this on the solution found in `torch.nn.utils.spectral_norm` :

```
def TopEigenvector(self, K, n_power_iterations=400, dim=1, eps=1e-12):
        v = torch.ones(K.shape[0],K.shape[1],1).to(self.device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            for _ in range(n_power_iterations):
                v = normalize(torch.bmm(K, v),dim=dim, eps=eps, out=v)
                if(n_power_iterations > 0):
                    v = v.clone(memory_format=torch.contiguous_format)
        return v
```

I have changed this to suit the problem as follows:

```
    def TopEigenvector(self, K, n_power_iterations=400, dim=1):
        v = torch.ones(K.shape[0],K.shape[1],1).to(self.device)
        for _ in range(n_power_iterations):
            m = torch.bmm(K, v)
            n = torch.norm(m, dim=1).unsqueeze(1)
            v = m/n
        return v
```

However, this relies on the dreaded for-loop, and is still slow, but faster than the original method.

Is there a better, faster method I could use?

Comment: Can you try an SVD?

Comment: The SVD takes longer, unfortunately.